# Open SQL database localdb on other computer

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, localdb

I'm create application in Visual Studio 2015 and i was created localdb in file .mdf

When i try open app on other computer (where is installed sql localdb 2014) i'm see error:
The database ....mdf cannot be opened because it is version 851. This server supports version 782 and earlier. A downgrade path is not supported.

My question is: How can I downgrade database or something else without reinstall sql localdb to version 2016 on other computer, or how can i decide how version will be created when i deploying my app?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

Install the database via ssdt/sqlpackage instead of deploying mdf files.